# How to get sorted output from find

Tags: sorting, unix, find

I have this command (thanx to  dgeorgiev):

```
find /somePath -maxdepth 1 -name "log.out*" -type f \
     -printf "Date: %TY-%Tm-%Td - Time: %TT - File: %f\n" -exec tail -n5 {} \;
```

I would like to have the output of it sorted by date & time, so that I get the newest files last. I guess that there is no way to tell the find-command to do so. So I might have to combine find, sort, tail somehow. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend adding another field to your output for the unix timestamp. In gnu find's `-printf` format string, this is represented as `%T@`.

For example, to sort everything you can do this:

```
find / -type f -printf "%T@ Date: %TY-%Tm-%Td - Time: %TT - File: %f\n" \
    | LC_ALL=C sort -n -k1,1 \
    | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

`sort -n -k1,1` sorts the lines in stdin numerically on the first column (and only the first column). The `LC_ALL=C` environment variable is just for paranoia. `sort` behaves differently depending on the locale.

That last `cut` at the end is to remove the unix timestamp if you don't want it in the output.

There are some alternatives as well, I'll briefly sketch those and their downsides.

- Using `ls`

If you're trying to list just the files in the current directory (hence the maxdepth of one), then you can use `ls -al` and look for lines starting with `-` rather than `d` or `l` (to filter out the directories and symlinks). This is a quick and dirty way to get the file names in sorted order and move on. Don't use it for untrusted input or filenames that can contain weird characters, it will break in mysterious ways.

```
/bin/ls -latr | grep '^-'
```

Warnings about parsing the output of `ls` here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

- When you don't have GNU find, but you do have perl.

Here's a more robust way of doing things (that only chokes on newlines in file names) and avoids spawning processes on a per-file basis. The thing that we're interested in is the timestamp (in this case the `mtime` (modified), there's also `ctime` (created) and `atime` (accessed).

You can use perl to access the `mtime` from the file as a unix timestamp, print it before the file name (separated by a space), sort numerically on the first column, and then remove the timestamp. Granted the has the unfortunate drawback of `stat`ing the file twice, once inside `find` and once inside `perl`.

```
find / -type f | head -n 1000 \
    | perl -ne 'chomp; @a = stat($_); print($a[9], " ", $_, "\n");' \
    | LC_ALL=C sort -n -k1,1 \
    | cut -d' ' -f2-
```